# display multiple values from html form checkbox in another checkbox using AJAX, PHP and MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have to select sub-category according to the category checked. i am stuck with selecting multiple checkboxes and displaying its value using ajax. 
i want to use pure ajax and not jquery. i am fetching values of 1 checkbox from database table and now i need to display other checkbox with the values fetched with select query depending upon the multiple checkboxes user checks. i have an idea foreach loop is to be used but cant understand how and where to frame it..Please Help. Thank u.
this is the form:

```
<?php
while($f1=mysql_fetch_row($res))  {
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkcat[]" id="chkcat" onChange="showUser(this.value)" value='<?php echo $f1[1]; ?>'>  <?php echo $f1[0]; ?>
<? } ?>
<div> id="txtHint"> </div>
```

Ajax code that has showUser function

```
<script>
 function showUser(str) {
 if (str=="") {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
} 

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_chkbox.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

and the file that has to fetch sub category according to the category selected and url i.e:ajax_chkbox.php is:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<input type=checkbox name=chksubcat[] id=chsubkcat value= $row[0]>  $row[2]"; 
echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: My first bit of advice to you would be, separate out your logic. PHP really should only do server side processing. jQuery - DOM Manipulate. KnockoutJS - data binding in the UI. You may find it easier to use different libraries for different parts of your app. Its easier for testing, easier for debugging

Comment: umm okay but i dont really know that..

Comment: "i want to use pure ajax and not jquery"??? Ajax isn't a library

Comment: oh ok..i actually searched for an answer and in return got lots of jquery thing..so just mentioned it as my requirement :)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what are you trying to achieve, do you need to fill **subcategories**, based on **category** selection?

And is that category on `checkbox`? That means you can select multiple items, unless you are looking for a `radio input` 

Why can't you use jQuery? that library has a useful purpose and save you from a lot of headaches.

Comment: @DannyG yes i am using checkbox that can select multiple values..i am using ajax n nt jQuery as i dont know jQuery at all! i did see some of the solutions with jQuery but dint understand anything..that's why..

Answer (score 0):

You can change Dropdown to checkbox

select_cat.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".category").change(function()
{
var id=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "select_subcat.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$(".subcat").html(html);
}
});

});

});
</script>
```

Category :

```
<select name="category" class="category">
<option selected="selected">--Select Category--</option>
<?php
include('databasefile');
mysql_connect($server,$username,$password)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database)or die(mysql_error());
$sql=mysql_query("select cat_name from category order by cat_name");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$cname=$row['cat_name'];
echo '<option value="'.$cname.'">'.$cname.'</option>';
} ?>
</select> <br/><br/>

SubCategory :
<select name="subcat" class="subcat">
<option selected="selected">--Select SubCat--</option>
</select>
```

2.select_subcat.php

```
<?php
include('databasefile);
mysql_connect($server,$username,$password)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database)or die(mysql_error());
if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
$sql=mysql_query("select s_name from subcat_l1 where cat_name='$id'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$sname=$row['s_name'];
echo '<option value="'.$sname.'">'.$sname.'</option>';
}
}
?>
SubCategory :
<select name="subcat" class="subcat">
<option selected="selected">--Select SubCat--</option>
</select>
```